# Whats the easiest way to use global variables in twig templates

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I need to inject a HTML file from another website into my base.html.twig file.

One solution would be to use the php function 'file_get_contents' within my controller and make it available to the template like so:

```
$globalFooter = file_get_contents('http://mysite.co.uk/footer/footer.html.twig');

return $this->render('ImagineGdmBundle:Default:product.html.twig', array('globalFooter' => $globalFooter));
```

But that would mean having to implement the code above to every controller function that uses the footer. Is there a better way?

Im sure there must be a way to create a global variable and make them available to my base.html.twig template...but I am new to Symfony and am unsure how to do it. Any suggestions??

Comment: The other website is serving `twig` files or directly the rendered HTML?

Comment: The other website is also serving twig files. I need to get the content of this file and injecting it into another template on another website

Comment: Cannot remember much Symfony but you must be able to subclass something so you call you special class when you want this to happen.

Comment: @BobFlemming please don't revert moderator edits, this question is not related to symfony1 at all, so those tags should be removed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question well explained in documentation about [twig global variables](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/global_variables.html). Your situation requires create [twig extension](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/twig_extension.html). It would be a simlpe function that you can call anywhere in your templates.

Comment: I ended up creating my own extension. Details can be seen in my other question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975005/creating-my-first-twig-extension-to-provide-global-variables-to-base-templates/17975310?noredirect=1#17975310

Comment: This is more likely considered as a link-only answer. Please add an example snippet to your answer, if you don't mind